# asp.net LinkButton in javascript not getting called when trying to send mail

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel, lightbox

```
         <div class="popup" id="invite-box">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
            <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
            <div class="popup-holder">
                <div class="popup-frame">
                    <div class="container"> 
                        <div action="#" class="invite-form" >


                                        <div class="email">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>

                                        <div class="textarea">
                                            <div class="textarea-holder">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns="30"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                <div class="btn-holder">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-view">View sample e-mail</a>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CssClass="btn-send" 
                                        onclick="LinkButton6_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

This is my pop up code and i am trying to send a mail on linkbutton click however the LinkButton_Click does not get called in the code behind

My code behind is as follows:

```
    protected void LinkButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Not getting called
{
    if (r1.Checked == true)
    {

        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.Subject = "Some one has invited you: Join abc! Meet ## of %%";
            mail.Body = mee.data[0].name+"</br>"+TextBox1.Text;
            mail.To.Add(TextBox2.Text);

            ////send the message

            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****", "*****");
            //mySmtpClient.Port="25";
            mySmtpClient.Host = "abc";
            mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mySmtpClient.Credentials = myCredential;
            mySmtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

i think my code is considering the linkbutton as javascript Button 
  [image]

Thanks

Comment: How are you clicking the LinkButton?  The `Text` property is not set, and there is no text between the open and close tags.   Does it even render as anything?

Comment: It is the css styling that displays the text

Comment: Do you know that the event is really never being called? Is it possible the code is being called, you just aren't getting the email? Have you tried to step in with the debugger? There isn't anything obviously wrong with the code you posted, so I wondered.

Comment: Its not being called thats the main issue the debugger doesnt go inside the LinkButton_Click which is very weird

Comment: all my problem is because of ajax that is used for the css i am not getting any values in the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think your missing triggers in update panel. add below triggers in just before closing tag of update panel

```
<Triggers>                      
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton6" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this may help...

Comment: I have modify my answer..just strike...might it help

Comment: If ChildrenAsTriggers="true" he wouldn't have to set a manual trigger, would he?

Comment: earlier days when I was using update panel I had face same problem and resolve with placing triggers. @VINI please try it if it works...

Comment: if it not work then I have some other solution but its patch..if @VINI you want I can provide u

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your question...

I would say that the link button you are showing is not the same as the link button in the source.

I tried to replicate your issue with a link button that had Invite as its text

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton6_Click">Invite</asp:LinkButton>
```

You can see in the source it contains Invite between the tags.

In your source there is no mention of Invite

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CssClass="btn-send"                                             onclick="LinkButton6_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Try adding another Link button, double click on it, add your code to it and try again.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" onClick="LinkButton6_Click">invite</asp:LinkButton> this is what mine looks like as well however it isnt working

Comment: That is because of the changes i am making to make run somehow

Comment: Add a new link button and try it - seems like it is messing up somehow with the existing one